# Regular Expression to Extract Text Bounded by '/'

Tags: regex, gedcom

I need to a regular expression to extract names from a GEDCOM file.  The format is:

Fred Joseph /Smith/

Where the text bounded by the / is the surname and the Fred Joseph are the forenames.  The complication is that the surname could be at any place in the text or may not be there at all.  I need something that will extract the surname and capture everything else as the forenames.

This is as far as I have got and I have tried making groups optional with the ? qualifier but to no avail:

[image: What I have so far]

As you can see it has several problems:  If the surname is missing nothing gets captured, the forename(s) sometimes have leading and trailing spaces, and I have 3 capture groups when I'd really like 2.  Even better would be if the capture group for the surname didn't include the '/' characters.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your last line, I'm not sure there is a way to *join* the group 1 with group 3 into a single group.

Here is my proposed solution. It doesn't capture spaces around forenames.

```
^(?:\h*([a-z\h]+\b)\h*)?(?:\/([a-z\h]+)\/)?(?:\h*([a-z\h]+\b)\h*)?$
```

To correctly match the names, care to use the **insensitive** flag, and if you test all lines at once, use **multiline** flag.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/GhD8mm/1)

#### Explanation

- `^` start of the line
- `(?:\h*([a-z\h]+\b)\h*)?` first non-capturing group that matches 0 or 1 time:

  - `\h*` 0 or more horizontal spaces
  - `([a-z\h]+\b)` captures in a group letters and spaces, but stops at the end of the last word
  - `\h*` matches the possible remaining spaces without capturing
- `(?:\/([a-z\h]+)\/)?` second non-capturing group that matches 0 or 1 time a name in a capturing group surrounded by slashes
- `(?:\h*([a-z\h]+\b)\h*)?` third non-capturing group doing the same as first one, capturing the names in a third group.
- `$` end of the line

Comment: Wow, thanks Niitaku.  No wonder I couldn't figure this out.  Appreciate the clear explanation too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements

```
([A-z a-z /])+\w*
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUmoe.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sandeep.  Doesn't seem to work for me.  Added a \ before the / but still didn't capture as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I follow what language is being used to extract the data, but based on what you have so far, you simply need to add '?':

```
(.*)(\/?.*\/?)(.*)
```

Not that this does not give you groupings for EACH name as some solutions will have multiple names in a single group

Edit:

Extending on Niitaku solution and looking at having each individual name in its own group, you could use:

```
^\s*(?:\/?([a-z]+)\/?)\s*(?:\/?([a-z]+)\/?)\s*(?:\/?([a-z]+)\/?)\s*$
```

As explained though, if using a language like ruby it would simply be:

```
ruby -pe '$_ = $_.scan(/\w+/)' file
```

Comment: Thanks grail.  When I do that the first capture group captures everything including, i.e., Fred Joseph /Smith/.  I am using NSRegularExpression, but testing using https://regex101.com with the pcre flavour.

Comment: Something I am confused on, what is the desired output?  Should we be capturing the '/' as part of a group or do you just want the names?

Comment: Just the names.  Ideally, 1st capture would be 'Fred Joseph' and the 2nd capture group 'Smith'.  HTMS Dave

Comment: You either need to account for all scenarios if simply using a regex machine, but if using a language (like ruby) I could deliver all the names easily

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps
`(.\*?)\\/(.\*?)\\/(.\*)`

Comment: A great answer on StackOverflow includes more than just some code. You can improve your answer by explaining what's going on so that people can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `^([^/]*)(/[^/]+/)?([^/]*)$`

This matches the following:

- `^` start of string (or with multiline modifier start of line)
- `([^/\n]*)` anything other than `/` or new line zero or more times - this is captured as group 1

  - `(/[^/\n]+/)?` a single `/` followed by one or more non `/` or new line characters, then a single '/' character - this is captured as group 2, and is optional
  - `([^/\n]*)` anything other than `/` or new line zero or more times - this is captured as group 3
  - `$` end of string (or with multiline modifier end of line)

You can see in action with your example text here: https://regex101.com/r/9kmKpy/1

To not capture the slashes you can add a non capturing group by adding ?: to the second set of brackets, and then adding another pair between the slashes:
`^([^\/\n]*)(?:\/([^\/\n]+)\/)?([^\/\n]*)$`

https://regex101.com/r/9kmKpy/2